# pylint fails with "unable to import moto", python can import it

Tags: python, pylint, moto

I'm trying to `pylint` my testsuite that uses `moto` module for AWS API mockup.

This is my super simple testcase:

```py
import moto
```

Unfortunately it fails `pylint`:

```
~/prj $ pylint test_moto.py 
************* Module test_test
test_moto.py:1:0: E0401: Unable to import 'moto' (import-error)
test_moto.py:1:0: W0611: Unused import moto (unused-import)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at -50.00/10 (previous run: -50.00/10, +0.00)
```

However I do have `moto` installed in my virtualenv and it works:

```
~/prj $ python
Python 3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import moto
>>> moto.__version__
'1.3.14'
>>>
```

This is my `pylint`:

```
~/prj $ pylint --version
pylint 2.3.1
astroid 2.2.5
Python 3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
```

Both `python` and `pylint` are in the virtualenv:

```
~/prj $ which python
/home/me/.virtualenvs/prjenv/bin/python
~/prj $ which pylint
/home/me/.virtualenvs/prjenv/bin/pylint
```

Why is pylint complaining about the import? How can I stop it?

Comment: Run the pylint that is installed by the python you use to run your code. If both are in different places (e.g. one in a venv and the other a global system component) then things can go awry.

Comment: @Jens thanks for the suggestion, they are both in the virtual env. I have updated the question.

Comment: Do you have a file `moto.py` that might shadow the module?

Comment: @Jens nope, only `test_moto.py` and `main.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it's an issue with `pylint 2.3.x` that doesn't work well with `boto3` and in turn with `moto`. See https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/3261

Downgrading to **`pylint 2.2.x`** solves this problem.